# LiveData doesn't apdating its value after first call in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm trying to get the last id added from entity A to entity B to add to entity B by it , I fetched the id of the last element added to entity A like this :

in Dao :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insert(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) : Long
```

and in fun insert in repo i used mutableLiveData to save the last id inserted and get it to viewmodel then to observing it in fragment

in repo :

```
class AddSpendRepository(private var database: PersonalAccountingDateBase) {

private var id : Long = 0
private var mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Long>()

suspend fun insert(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity){
    id = database.getAddSpendDao().insert(addSpendEntity)
    Log.e("addspendrepository",id.toString())
    mutableLiveData.postvalue(id)
    Log.e("addspendrepositoryid",mutableLiveData.value.toString())
    ...
}}
fun getMutableLiveData() : MutableLiveData<Long> = mutableLiveData
```

and in VM :

```
    fun insertSpend(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    addSpendRepository.insert(addSpendEntity)
}

fun getMutableLiveData() : MutableLiveData<Long> = addSpendRepository.getMutableLiveData()
```

the observer in fragment i try to add to entity B When mutableLiveData is change :

```
private fun insert()
{
    val totalMoney = binding.edtAddSpendSpendMoney.text.toString().toInt()
    val notice = binding.edtAddSpendNotice.text.toString()
    val date = binding.txtAddSpendDateText.text.toString()
    val addSpendEntity = AddSpendEntity(totalMoney,notice,date)
    addSpendViewModel.insertSpend(addSpendEntity)
    addSpendViewModel.getMutableLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
    Observer {
        Log.e("addspendfragment",it.toString())
        if(it.toInt() != 0)
        {
            val dailyMovementEntity = DailyMovementEntity("make",totalMoney,notice,5,it.toInt())
            addSpendViewModel.insertDailyMovement(dailyMovementEntity)
        }
        
    })
```

so the problem i faced is when to insert in the first time the value of mutable get null and the observer does'nt notice any thing then in the second time the observer notice the previos state of id and this condition continues as long as the application is running , when i close the app and do the same in the same way : The same problem is repeated as shown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzM0u.png)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show it in your code, so I'm just guessing, but here's a possible cause of your issue.

I'm guessing your ViewModel's `insertSpend` function is doing something like this:

```
fun insertSpend(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(addSpendEntity)
    }
}
```

The problem is, if you call `MutableLiveData.value` on a thread other than the main thread, then the change is not viewable until another loop of the main thread has occurred. You're not supposed to call `.value` on any thread besides the main thread. Then you get the proper value in your observer because observers are called on the next loop of the main thread.

Also, a suspend function should never require being called from a specific dispatcher, so you should not need to specify `Dispatchers.IO` when you launch your coroutine. More properly, your repository function should look like this, so it is safe to call it from anywhere. Any time a suspend function calls a function that requires a specific dispatcher, it is best to specify that dispatcher internally (I think of this as an extension of the single responsibility principle--outside functions shouldn't have to know what state to specify when calling another function if it can be avoided).

I would define it like this:

```
suspend fun insert(addSpendEntity: AddSpendEntity) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    id = database.getAddSpendDao().insert(addSpendEntity) // it's safe to call this on main because it's a suspend function which by convention must not block
    Log.e("addspendrepository",id.toString())
    mutableLiveData.value = id
    Log.e("addspendrepositoryid",mutableLiveData.value.toString())
    // ...
}
```

Just my opinion:

On the ViewModel side, in general, you should rarely ever be launching a coroutine on the ViewModel scope with a specific dispatcher. Android has a general convention of treating the main thread as the default, and it is full of functions that must be called on main for proper behavior. So it is clean to always leave that as your default and only use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` (or `.Default`) for the bits of your coroutine that need it. And you should never need those just to call suspend functions, because of the coroutine convention that suspend functions must never block. So you only need them when calling blocking code.

Comment: the prblem didn't work and i get error : Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread , any way i update my question and i use .postvalue instead .value also not wrok

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code if you have to use `postValue`. If you call it from Dispatchers.Main, it will not give that error when using .value.. Notice my code above uses `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {` to surround the content of the function in your repo. Using `.postValue` will change the value later, on the next frame of the main function, so that will still result in your original issue. I am also recommending that you remove `(Dispatchers.IO)` from your ViewModel function, although that shouldn't be necessary if you make the suggested change to your repo function.

Comment: i try with it , yes it pass a right id to mutable in repo but the observer still not observe in the first call and every time i do the insert it observe the prev value

Comment: Your log in your original question shows that the observer is getting the right value, though. But if you check the value on the main thread immediately after firing off the coroutine, it won't be ready yet, because `.value` will be set in the future, after the database transaction is finished.

Comment: yes totaly agree with you but why the observer not observe in the first time although  i put all your code